# How to correctly parse response from API in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

API returns data in simple string format, e.g.

```
SID=null
LSID=null
Auth=G2UlCa...Fx
```

How to correctly parse it in AngularJS $http.get function to get an object with keys and values? Should I just simply split() the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split() should be best way for this api return,API returns is best to use a common format (EX:json).